# Azure DevOps failing on "npm install"

Tags: azure-devops, npm-install

We have a CD/CI Azure DevOps build pipeline that stop working all of a sudden today.  It has been invoked successfully in our pipeline for months on end.

The component that fails is the "npm install" , it fails with the following error in the verbose log:

[image]

I google around and some suggested to run: npm cache clear --force prior to npm install.
I tried that but same error persists.

Then I look up earlier in the log and see the following:

[image]

I tried to browse to https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.12.0/win32-x64-83_binding.node and got the message "Page not found".

I cannot tell if this is related to the root cause why npm fails but it seems to back my assumption that something is not right with "npm install" as of this time of writing (Nov 17, 2020).

Anyone else using Azure DevOps for CD/CI having the same issue?
I look at NPM incident page and see this issue https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/r1tlhscrw3r6 but it should have been fixed.

Comment: Try running `npm audit` to see if it can find any issues. If it does, you can fix them by running `npm audit fix`.

Comment: @Fylix any chance you've updated `node.js` on the server recently? It seems like it tries to build `node-sass` against a node version that is not supported.

Comment: Hi Max, this is done using the Azure DevOps pipeline agent so I have no control over any on premise or any specific VM for this node.js setup.  I noticed the npm version has updated from 6.14.6 (our last build) to 6.14.8 when I review the log.

Comment: The default version was updated on the agents.  You can see breaking changes at the github for the images.  https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/1953.  Going from Node.js 12.x to 14.x.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recently, a [breaking change](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/1953) was made to the default Azure DevOps agent images for the default version of Node.js.  It was incremented from 12.x to 14.x.

> **Breaking changes**
>
> Default version of Node.JS on images will be updated
> from 12.x to 14.x
>
> **Target date**
>
> For Windows, Ubuntu images, rollout of this change will
> start on 2 November 2020 and will take 3-4 days For MacOS images,
> rollout will start on 9 November.
>
> **The motivation for the changes**
>
> On images, we always install LTS
> version of Node.JS by default. On 2020-10-27, Node.JS 14 has become
> LTS version. On 2020-11-30, Node.JS 12 will be switched to Maintenance
> mode.
>
> **Possible impact**
>
> If you rely on default Node.JS version and your
> project is not compatible to Node.JS 14, it might start to fail
>
> **Mitigation ways**
>
> Please consider using Node.js [Tool Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/node-js?view=azure-devops) (for Azure DevOps) and
> setup-node (for GitHub Actions) to switch back to Node.JS 12.
> Switching will take less than a second. Node.JS 12 still will be
> available on images along with Node.JS 8, 10.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I'll review it but it looks like this is it, our Azure Pipelines also use windows-2019 agent specification.

Answer (score 10):

Based on [@Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64883556/281084), I'll post the fragment of yml you need to fix this:

```yaml
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
```

Answer (score 10):

For anyone still using the graphical UI rather than YML files, you would add a
"**Node.js tool installer**" task and configure its version. It would look something like this (where the Version Spec contains the version of node.js you want run):
[image]
Also note that it is **BEFORE** the "**npm install**" task!!

Comment: Do we need to do npm install every time we make an Angular build? is there any way to ignore the npm install if not needed?

Comment: @Schatak Yes. You will need to call npm install each time.  Think of it as a clean environment upon each run.  It has no idea what you did on your previous run.  This is also very desirable because you don't want things laying around that may cause build issues if you upgrade or delete things.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My worry was I had a few node packages, which we modified as per project need, which we do not want to override with nmp insall. So that's why I was looking for an option to ignore, or maybe stop overriding those particular packages with npm insall

Comment: @Schatak I would suggest forking the package in question and putting it into your own feed.  DevOps has feeds that can handle NuGet or NPM packages (and many other types).   You would then use a .npmrc file to add the additional feed (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69264093/97803) other post where someone forgot to add the upstream feed).   Personally, I've never set this up but I believe this could put you on a path to fixing the issue.