# Add Additional npm packages on Azure DevOps Feed

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, azure-devops, .npmrc

I use Angular 2.4 for my project and the project contains `.npmrc` file that uses an internal register. Currently the build pipeline is returning this error:

> No matching version found for yargs@^3.32.0. In most cases you or one
> of your dependencies are requesting a package version that doesn't
> exist.

My project is using `uglify-js` npm package and `yargs` npm package is one of its dependencies. Therefore, I have added `yargs` and `uglify-js` to package.json to see if it will make the error from Azure DevOp build go away, which it doesn't.

Here's the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.5.3",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "@microsoft/1ds-analytics-web-js": "^3.1.6",
    "@microsoft/1ds-properties-js": "^3.1.6",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.29",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "2.17.*",
    "ng2-translate": "~5.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "~0.8.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~5.5.6",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "extendify": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "5.4.5",
    "tslint": "^3.8.1",
    "typescript": "4.2.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "yargs": "^3.32.0",
    "uglify-js": "^2.8.28"
  }
}
```

However, I am encountering this error in my build pipeline:

> No matching version found for yargs@^3.32.0. In most cases you or one
> of your dependencies are requesting a package version that doesn't
> exist.

In my build pipeline, I have added `.npmrc` file with the register url, which connects to the feed. And in the feed, this `yargs` package does not exist. I was wondering how to add additional npm package to the feed?

Answer (score 0):

> Add Additional npm packages on Azure DevOps Feed

To resolve this issue, you could add the npmjs.com as Upstream sources for your feed:

Please check the document [Use packages from npmjs.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops):

> 1. Edit your feed. Select the gear icon in the top right of the page to
>    open feed settings.
> 2. Select the Upstream sources pivot.
> 3. Select Add upstream source in the CommandBar.
> 4. Select Select a feed URL and select npmjs.com
>    (https://registry.npmjs.org). If you like, customize the upstream
>    name.
> 5. Select Add.

Alternatively, you could install the package yargs by the command:

```
npm install yargs
```

or clone this project on github:

```
git clone http://github.com/bcoe/yargs.git
```

Then we could [Publish an npm package from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/publish?view=azure-devops).